# I Do Anything on WoM, and it Goes to the Pause Menu and Won't Let me Out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, linux

I downloaded WoM and XWoM and so everytime I build or break something, and it goes to the pause menu. I click `Back to Game` and it does not. So effectively I am trapped in the pause menu.

I have Java 7, (because it is pre-installed on Linux Mint), and I really don't want to use the Default Client for Minecraft.

Comment: Check your key bindings.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Forgive me for being so stupid at some things, but what are keybindings?

Comment: Your controls settings in the menu.

Comment: Okay, but actually breaks or adds the blocks though

Comment: @Alèx Sorry, your last comment doesn't make any sense. Could you explain? Have you checked your controls settings? What is your Button 1 and Button 2 set to?

Answer (score 1):

Did you say you tried to click "Back to Game" but instead placing and breaking blocks?

Anyway, this input handling issue is a long known bug of Minecraft for Linux.

The first thing you should try is running Minecraft with Java 6. Many claimed that Minecraft works better in JRE 6, hopefully this is a solution for you.

If the above doesn't work, please download, extract and replace your lwjgl file. You can download it [here](http://lwjgl.org/download.php).

Supposing that you know how to use Linux, please try to run this command in terminal and tell us the output(This is a test of your PC's graphic support, not going to download/install anything):

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```